# Hibernate filter associations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I am quite unfamiliar with Hibernate and JPA and am struggling to understand how I query/filter associations on an entity. Currently I have 2 entities; user and measurement where a user can have many measurements and a measurement belongs to a user. This can be seen within the classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "user_id"))
public class User extends Model {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "associatedUser")
    public List<Measurement> measurements;

    ...

}

@Entity
@Table(name="measurements")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "measurement_id"))
public class Measurement extends Model {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "associatedUser", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    public User associatedUser;

    ...

}
```

This works fine and I am able to grab all measurements from a user by accessing the user's `measurements` attribute. However what if I want to apply a query or filter to the users measurements to, say, only give me those measurements after a certain data. Ideally I do not want to grab all the measurements and then filter.

I have played with the idea of using the `@Filter` annotations but I am not sure whether this is the best way to go. I believe I could also try using the Hibernate Criteria API?

Any pointers here would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say using `@Filter` annotation is the best way to go.

[Hibernate Filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html)

*Hibernate Criteria Api* is just `HQL` in object oriented way, so it doesn't offer any further capabilites different from HQL